# Div background-color change upon drop-down

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I knew javaScript but I'm not used to it as I'm more focus on creating UI design. So decided to take up some short courses and then I've encountered this problem. There should be dropdown which consist of 4 items to choose: red, blue, green, yellow. If a user choose a color let's say yellow, the div box underneath will become yellow. I used Bootstrap for this by the way.

My code goes something like this ` Dropdown 1

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li id="red"><a href="#">Red</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Blue</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Green</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Yellow</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`
Full code resides here 
http://jsfiddle.net/0c4dbr9t/7/

Comment: So what's the issue precisely? Your style rule is referencing the class `.box` by the way, and not the ID `#box` as it is in your source code.

Comment: Oh crap. I didn't noticed that. Being a dumb noob at this point.

Comment: Thank you for that heads up. Yeah I forgot '.' is for class and '#' is for id.

Comment: Been there before, I still like to visit occasionally :) You know that your current vanilla javascript set-up will only apply to your first `li` element, since it's the only one with an ID defined, and the only one referenced in your javascript snippet, right?

Comment: Yup. The first 'li' element only will be applied since it is the one being define on the script. But Im planning to add more colors onto it. I guess it's better if I'll use jQuery for this, your thoughts?

Comment: If your focus is leaning more towards UI design, it may be a better idea to focus on familiarizing yourself with jQuery, It really doesn't hurt knowing javascript too, and I wouldn't recommend using an entire library when simple vanilla javascript will do, but it is a better introduction to that language for those starting out. Now in this case, you can achieve your intended effect with far fewer lines of code using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Yes I'm more into UI design and I guess I really need to get myself used with Javascript or jQuery to make my designs go live by adding interactions instead of just merely designing them alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple code

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0c4dbr9t/13/)

Code:

```
<div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn " href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
 <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li data-color="red"><a href="#">Red</a>
        </li>
        <li data-color="blue"><a href="#">Blue</a>
        </li>
        <li data-color="green"><a href="#">Green</a>
        </li>
        <li data-color="yellow"><a href="#">Yellow</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id ="box"><div>

$( document ).ready(function() {
 $('.dropdown-menu li').click(function(){
        var color = $(this).data("color");

        $("#box").css('background-color',color);
        });
});
```

Comment: That's nice. I haven't tried using that 'data-color' attribute. Was that a part of HTML5?

Comment: Definition of 'data' attribute https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if this is what you needed..

**html**

```
<div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn " href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
 <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>

    <ul id="dd" class="dropdown-menu">
       <li><a href="#">Red</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blue</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Green</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Yellow</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id ="box"><div>
```

**css**

```
#box {
margin-top: 20px;
background-color: #000;
padding: 50px;
}
```

**js**

```
var ul = document.getElementById('dd');
ul.addEventListener("click", changeColor, false);

function changeColor (e) {
  if(e.target.nodeName == "A") {
       document.getElementById("box").style.background =e.target.innerHTML;
    }

}
```

Comment: Your code seems fine as well. Will try to play my head around your code snippet guys. Thanks for this. I really need to get myself used with this programming language even I knew how hard it is.

Comment: Thanks for acknowledging.  I used pure javascript that's why code seems bigger. Using jquery will be good option if you are familiar.

Answer (score 0):

Using simple javascript:

```html
<div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn " href="#">Dropdown 1</a>
 <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><span class="caret"></span></a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="red"><a href="#">Red</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blue</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Green</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Yellow</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id ="box"> Some Text <div>
<script>
var menu = document.querySelector("ul.dropdown-menu");
menu.onclick = function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.target.innerText)
 document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = evt.target.innerText;
}
</script>
```